# Tomcat catalina.out is 40GB

Tags: java, tomcat

I wonder why my spring project with tomcat server got `catalina.out` file with size 40GB. Any solutions, please.

[image: catalina.out reach 40 GB]

Comment: u need to take backup that file and compress it.then remove that file.

Comment: or try to decrease logging level

Comment: Ugh, I have never thought the file could swell to the such enormous size.

Comment: Do you know what `catalina.out` is? It's a text file, you can look at the contents (and delete the whole file if you want).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

catalina.out reaches such a large size because:

1- there might be many logging messages sent to console handler, and

2- also there is not any rotation of catalina.out (and no policy to remove older catalina.out).

First, as there might be some duplication and the messages in catalina.out , which could also be stored in *log messages too, I'd check if the contents of the log files (catalina.[DATE].log) are the same as those of catalina.out, if so then you can edit file **conf/logging.properties** and [remove console handler](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/catalina-logs-are-not-rotated-or-removed-289276264.html)

I'd also check the level of the log messages and set a higher level if possible. Look for this line in **conf/logging.properties**

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ....
```

Possible levels, in increasing level of frequency are SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST or ALL. I'd try replace ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE by CONFIG or even INFO. For instance, by setting it to INFO, all SEVERE, WARNING and INFO messages will be logged but not any with a level to the right of that list.

Also another option is set a limit to console handler by adding this line to **conf/logging.properties**

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.limit = 1024000
```

and [rotate catalina.out](https://dzone.com/articles/how-rotate-tomcat-catalinaout) configuring an automatic task to remove older ones.

Comment: @ChhunlyLim If the answer is OK then you should accept it

Comment: Thanks for your helps, three years till now, I still use your solution.

Comment: Glad to help @ChhunlyLim ;-)

Comment: Now log4j2 support added for tomcat (8.5 or later) versions, is it not better to  integrate with log4j2 instead of doing all these hacks?

Answer (score 4):

if you are linux user to handle this from system is pretty easy you can configure logrotation with logrotate this is very easy

Step : 1 (Create Logrotate file)

```
root@c2dapp01-usea1e# vim /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat
```

Step : Add rotation instruction for linux log rotator

```
/opt/tomcat/latest/logs/catalina.out {
    copytruncate
    daily
    rotate 7
    compress
    missingok
    size 100M
}
```

Step : 3 Add cron job to run daily in crond.daily or create custom cron (This file is by default there if not then only create)

```
root@c2dapp01-usea1e:# vim /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
# Clean non existent log file entries from status file
cd /var/lib/logrotate
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean
sed 's/"//g' status | while read logfile date
do
    [ -e "$logfile" ] && echo "\"$logfile\" $date"
done >> status.clean
mv status.clean status

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

This script can be run manually.

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the huge size of logs is due to the `DEBUG` mode setting of `log4j`. Change this setting to `WARN` and the size of logging will be reduced.

This is quite common to see `catalina.out` file expanding.

this could be used to clear the log of `catalina.out` file without stopping tomcat with the command below.

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/logs/catalina.out
```

To keep `catalina.out` smaller in size, either one of the following ways can be used:

1. You could use the above `Linux` command and add it to a `CronScheduler`
   to run daily/ weekly/ monthly or yearly as preferred.
2. Use `logrotate` tool in `Linux`. It is a log managing command-line tool
   in Linux. This can rotate the log files under different conditions.
   Particularly, **we can rotate log files on a fixed duration or if the
   file has grown to a certain size.** You can click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rotating-logs-logrotate#:%7E:text=logrotate%20is%20a%20log%20managing,manage%20the%20matching%20log%20files.) for more
   info on this.